# Input Text unfocuses after each character is typed in, but it seems to be a target issue within React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a table using Material UI Table. I want to populate by fetching from api, which seems fine. Now, each row should display two buttons, one for removing that row by using the **filter()** method. And the other to modify the title.

For removing the row, I'm targeting the button's parent ID which (the TableRow ID) and I'm filtering all the elements of the array whose index does not match the TableRow ID, this seems to be working fine, only thing is I have to use `id - 1` so it matches the index number. That seems to be working fine.

For the editing of the title I'm having some issues. Here's the step by step process:

1. The Edit button toggles the disable value in the input so it becomes 'editable'. The `handleClickEdit` function sets new state for data so the input is enabled.
2. The input's onChange runs the `handleChange()` function, this creates a new array and based on the `id - 1` (like on the remove function) as an the index, it sets the title property of that object and then sets that new Array as the new state value for `data`. **One issue here is that on any character input the input field is unfocused and you have to click again to continue typing. Note that this doesn't happen if I use `id` instead of `id - 1`, but it changes the field below. **
3. The value is stored on state and when Done button is clicked, the `handleDone` function toggles the input field to disabled again.
4. An extra and annoying issue of this approach is that if you remove a row, and then want to edit a row below the one that was removed, the edit targets the row below instead of that actual row.

Here's my code:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

import {
  TablePagination,
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableFooter,
  TableContainer,
  TableRow,
  TableHead,
} from "@mui/material";

import TableCell from "@mui/material/TableCell";

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [toggleEdit, setToggleEdit] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos?_limit=5")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data.map((item) => ({ ...item, enableEdit: true })));
      });
  }, []);

  const removeRow = (e) => {
    const { id } = e.target.parentElement;
    let arr = data.filter((elem) => elem.id != id);
    setData(arr);
  };

  const handleClickEdit = (e) => {
    const { id } = e.target.parentElement;
    setToggleEdit(!toggleEdit);
    let newData = [...data];
    newData[id-1].enableEdit = !newData[id-1].enableEdit;
    setData(newData);
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { value, id } = e.target;
    let newData = [...data];
    newData[id-1].title = value;
    setData(newData);
  };

  const handleDone = (e) => {
    const { id } = e.target.parentElement;
    let newData = [...data];
    newData[id-1].enableEdit = !newData[id-1].enableEdit;

    setData(newData);
    console.log(data[id-1]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="table-container">
        <TableContainer>
          <Table>
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell>ID</TableCell>
                <TableCell>Album ID</TableCell>
                <TableCell>Title</TableCell>
                {/* <TableCell>Thumbnail</TableCell> */}
                <TableCell>Actions</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
              {data.map((row) => (
                <TableRow id={row.id} key={row.id}>
                  <TableCell key={row.id + "_id"} id={row.id + "_id"}>
                    {row.id}
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{row.albumId}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell key={row.title} id={row.title}>
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      disabled={row.enableEdit}
                      className="title"
                      defaultValue={row.title}
                      id={row.id}
                      onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
                      name={"title"}
                    />
                  </TableCell>
                  {/* <TableCell><img src={row.thumbnailUrl} /></TableCell> */}
                  <TableCell id={row.id}>
                    <button onClick={(e) => removeRow(e)}>Remove</button>
                    {row.enableEdit && (
                      <button onClick={(e) => handleClickEdit(e)}>Edit</button>
                    )}
                    {row.enableEdit === false && (
                      <button onClick={(e) => handleDone(e)}>Done</button>
                    )}
                  </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              ))}
            </TableBody>
            <TableFooter>
                </TableFooter>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this by creating a custom `Row` component that manages state for each row. This way you're not re-rendering every single row `onChange`.

Apologies that I haven't tested this code, but it should give you general idea of how to go about it.

The row component:

```js
const MyRow = ({ row, handleSave, handleRemove }) => {
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(row.title);

  return (
    <>
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell>{row.id}</TableCell>
        <TableCell>{row.albumId}</TableCell>
        <TableCell key={row.title} id={row.title}>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={value}
            disabled={disabled}
            className="title"
            defaultValue={row.title}
            onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
            name={"title"}
          />
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell>
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              if (disabled) {
                setDisabled(false);
              } else {
                //   save changes
                handleSave(row.id, value);
                // and disable editing
                setDisabled(true);
              }
            }}
          >
            {disabled ? "Edit" : "Save"}
          </button>
          {/* you didn't inclucde this in your code, but a 'cancel' button is probably handy */}
          {!disabled && (
            <button
              onClick={() => {
                setValue(row.title);
                setDisabled(true);
              }}
            >
              Cancel
            </button>
          )}
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell>
          <button onClick={() => handleRemove(row.id)}>Remove</button>
        </TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    </>
  );
};
```

Notice how you don't have to fuss with element `id` props here. In general I rarely find the need to use element IDs in React. The magic is to pass the row data itself into your event handler callbacks.

Define the `data` state handlers in your main component and pass them down to each row. Again, not fussing with `ids`, just making sure each row has a unique `key`.

```js
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos?_limit=5")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data.map((item) => ({ ...item, enableEdit: true })));
      });
  }, []);

  const handleSave = (id, value) => {
    // generate a new array from existin grows
    const newData = data.map((row) => {
      // update our row with the new value
      if (row.id === id) {
        return { ...row, title: value };
      }
      // not our row—leave it as-is
      return row;
    });
    // update our parent data state
    setData(newData);
  };

  const handleRemove = (id) => {
    let newData = data.filter((row) => row.id !== id);
    setData(newData);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="table-container">
        <TableContainer>
          <Table>
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell>ID</TableCell>
                <TableCell>Album ID</TableCell>
                <TableCell>Title</TableCell>
                {/* <TableCell>Thumbnail</TableCell> */}
                <TableCell>Actions</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
              {data.map((row) => (
                <MyRow
                  key={row.id}
                  row={row}
                  handleSave={handleSave}
                  handleRemove={handleRemove}
                />
              ))}
            </TableBody>
            <TableFooter></TableFooter>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you, this approach works beautifully and simplifies all the code.

Comment: glad to hear that!